# Delivered energy of a RLC circuit - proof

Tags: circuit-analysis, energy, education

I have an RLC circuit with two resistances \$R \$ and \$R_i \$ in serie.
On my book there is the expression of the stored energy (\$C \$ capacitance, \$E \$ voltage on the capacitor):

$$W_s = \frac{1}{2} C E^2$$

and the delivered energy:

$$W_d = W_s \frac{R}{R+R_i}$$

How can I get the latter expression?

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess \$W_d\$ is the "work done" by the resistor \$R\$? How would you go about calculating what work is done in a resistor in a "normal" DC circuit?

Comment: The same current goes through each resistor so the power dissipated (and therefore energy) is in proportion to the relative values of the resistors: \$\frac{R_i}{R+R_i}\$ and \$\frac{R}{R+R_i}\$

Answer (score 2):

By simple observation, when the charged capacitor connects to the right hand circuit, all the stored energy will be delivered to the resistors over time. It has nowhere else to go. That stored energy will be dissipated as heat.

Given that some proportion of that energy will be delivered to both resistors, is it clear to see that if they were equal in value, each would receive 50% of the original stored energy. So, do you really need any more help understanding the resistance ratio in your 2nd equation?

Comment: Hello @Andyaka can you show me the mathematical proof please?

Comment: If you asked me to use a complex spectrograph to tell you the colour of a *serinus canaria forma domestica*, I'd tell you that canaries are usually yellow. There is no mathematical proof that makes sense to your question because, by inspection all the energy stored in the capacitor eventually gets dissipated in the resistors. Sure it will be a diminishing sinewave of current with a frequency dependant on L and C but that is irrelevant - all the energy gets wasted into heat.